# Alinhar títulos em html

Tags: html

Tenho esta imagem onde pretendo alinhar todos os títulos rodeados a vermelho ao mesmo nível:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
echo '<div><table border="1"><th colspan="2">Infância</th><th colspan="3">Sénior</th><tr><td>';
echo '<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#58ACFA"><h5><strong>Creche I Utentes</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela1;
echo '<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#58ACFA"><h5><strong>Creche II Utentes</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela2;

echo "</td><td>";

echo '<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#58ACFA"><h5><strong>Infância Utentes</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela3;
echo '<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#FFFF00"><h5><strong>Jardim de Infância/Creche Colaboradores</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela4;
echo '<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#FF8000"><h5><strong>Total de Refeições</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela9;

echo "</td><td>";

echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#58ACFA"><h5><strong>Centro de Dia Utentes</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela5;
echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#FFFF00"><h5><strong>Centro de Dia Colaboradores</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela6;
echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#FF8000"><h5><strong>Total de Refeições</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela10;

echo "</td><td>";

echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#58ACFA"><h5><strong>Lar Utentes</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela7;
echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#FFFF00"><h5><strong>Lar Colaboradores</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela8;

echo "</td><td>";

echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#FF8000"><h5><strong>Total de Refeições</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela11;

echo '</td></tr></table></div>';
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table {
     width:150px;
    _width:150px;
    border:2px solid #CCC;
    border-spacing: 15 px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20;
    font-size: 12px;
    }
    th {
    color: #8B0000;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10px;
    }
     td {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
}

</style>
```

Comment: falta adicionar ai o css

Comment: já adicionei à pergunta

Comment: Para obter melhores respostas coloque o HTML gerado pelo PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Coloque uma classe nas células que devem ser alinhadas no topo `class="verticalAlignTop"`

**Código com as classes**

```
echo '<div><table border="1"><th colspan="2">Infância</th><th colspan="3">Sénior</th><tr><td class="verticalAlignTop">';
echo '<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#58ACFA"><h5><strong>Creche I Utentes</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela1;
echo '<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#58ACFA"><h5><strong>Creche II Utentes</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela2;

echo "</td><td class="verticalAlignTop">";

echo '<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#58ACFA"><h5><strong>Infância Utentes</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela3;
echo '<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#FFFF00"><h5><strong>Jardim de Infância/Creche Colaboradores</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela4;
echo '<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#FF8000"><h5><strong>Total de Refeições</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela9;

echo "</td><td>";

echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#58ACFA"><h5><strong>Centro de Dia Utentes</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela5;
echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#FFFF00"><h5><strong>Centro de Dia Colaboradores</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela6;
echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#FF8000"><h5><strong>Total de Refeições</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela10;

echo "</td><td class="verticalAlignTop">";

echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#58ACFA"><h5><strong>Lar Utentes</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela7;
echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#FFFF00"><h5><strong>Lar Colaboradores</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela8;

echo "</td><td>";

echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#FF8000"><h5><strong>Total de Refeições</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela11;

echo '</td></tr></table></div>';
```

> e no css adicione

```
.verticalAlignTop {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**Exemplo para simples teste - clique em `Executar`**

```css
     width:150px;
    _width:150px;
    border:2px solid #CCC;
    border-spacing: 15 px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20;
    font-size: 12px;
    }
    th {
    color: #8B0000;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10px;
    }
     td {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
}

.verticalAlignTop {
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div><table border="1"><th colspan="2">Infância</th><th colspan="3">Sénior</th><tr><td class="verticalAlignTop">
<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="text-align: center; background:#58ACFA"><h5><strong>Creche I Utentes</strong></h5></td> 
  <table border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td>aaaa</td>
    <td>ssss</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>dddd</td>
    <td>ffff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ggggg</td>
    <td>hhhhh</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>kkkkk</td>
    <td>lllll</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>zzzzz</td>
    <td>xxxxxx</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ccccc</td>
    <td>bbbbb;</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="text-align: center; background:#58ACFA"><h5><strong>Creche II Utentes</strong></h5></td> 
  <table border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td>aaaa</td>
    <td>ssss</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>dddd</td>
    <td>ffff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ggggg</td>
    <td>hhhhh</td>
   </tr>
  </table>

</td><td class="verticalAlignTop">

<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="text-align: center; background:#58ACFA"><h5><strong>Infância Utentes</strong></h5></td> 
  <table border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td>aaaa</td>
    <td>ssss</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>dddd</td>
    <td>ffff</td>
   </tr>

  </table>
<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="text-align: center; background:#FFFF00"><h5><strong>Jardim de Infância/Creche Colaboradores</strong></h5></td> 
  <table border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td>aaaa</td>
    <td>ssss</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>dddd</td>
    <td>ffff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ggggg</td>
    <td>hhhhh</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>kkkkk</td>
    <td>lllll</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>zzzzz</td>
    <td>xxxxxx</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ccccc</td>
    <td>bbbbb;</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="text-align: center; background:#FF8000"><h5><strong>Total de Refeições</strong></h5></td> 
  <table border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td>aaaa</td>
    <td>ssss</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>dddd</td>
    <td>ffff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ggggg</td>
    <td>hhhhh</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>ccccc</td>
    <td>bbbbb;</td>
   </tr>
  </table>

</td><td>

<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="text-align: center; background:#58ACFA"><h5><strong>Centro de Dia Utentes</strong></h5></td> 
  <table border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td>aaaa</td>
    <td>ssss</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>dddd</td>
    <td>ffff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ggggg</td>
    <td>hhhhh</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>zzzzz</td>
    <td>xxxxxx</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ccccc</td>
    <td>bbbbb;</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="text-align: center; background:#FFFF00"><h5><strong>Centro de Dia Colaboradores</strong></h5></td> 
  <table border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td>aaaa</td>
    <td>ssss</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>dddd</td>
    <td>ffff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ggggg</td>
    <td>hhhhh</td>
   </tr>


  </table>
<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="text-align: center; background:#FF8000"><h5><strong>Total de Refeições</strong></h5></td> 
  <table border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td>aaaa</td>
    <td>ssss</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>dddd</td>
    <td>ffff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ggggg</td>
    <td>hhhhh</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>kkkkk</td>
    <td>lllll</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>zzzzz</td>
    <td>xxxxxx</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ccccc</td>
    <td>bbbbb;</td>
   </tr>
  </table>

</td><td  class="verticalAlignTop">

<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="text-align: center; background:#58ACFA"><h5><strong>Lar Utentes</strong></h5></td> 
  <table border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td>aaaa</td>
    <td>ssss</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>dddd</td>
    <td>ffff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ggggg</td>
    <td>hhhhh</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>kkkkk</td>
    <td>lllll</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>zzzzz</td>
    <td>xxxxxx</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ccccc</td>
    <td>bbbbb;</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="text-align: center; background:#FFFF00"><h5><strong>Lar Colaboradores</strong></h5></td> 
  <table border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td>aaaa</td>
    <td>ssss</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>dddd</td>
    <td>ffff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ggggg</td>
    <td>hhhhh</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>kkkkk</td>
    <td>lllll</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>zzzzz</td>
    <td>xxxxxx</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ccccc</td>
    <td>bbbbb;</td>
   </tr>
  </table>

</td><td>

<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="text-align: center; background:#FF8000"><h5><strong>Total de Refeições</strong></h5></td> 
  <table border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td>aaaa</td>
    <td>ssss</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>dddd</td>
    <td>ffff</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ggggg</td>
    <td>hhhhh</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>kkkkk</td>
    <td>lllll</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>zzzzz</td>
    <td>xxxxxx</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ccccc</td>
    <td>bbbbb;</td>
   </tr>
  </table>

</td></tr></table></div>
```

Comment: Como alinho verticalmente os títulos dentro das células onde tem por exemplo  **"Creche I Utentes"**?

Answer (score 2):

Para alinhar o conteúdo ao topo de uma coluna em tabelas, use `valign="top"`:

```
<td valign="top">
    conteúdo
</td>
```

Esse desalinhamento acontece quando a altura da `td` é maior que o seu conteúdo e o valor padrão de `valign` é `middle`.

**Exemplo:**

```html
<table height="100" border="1">
   <tr>
      <td valign="top">
         alinhado ao topo
      </td>
      <td>
         não alinhado
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
         alinhado ao topo
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Pela estrutura da sua tabela, você deve colocar `valign="top"` nos seguintes locais:

**Na 1ª linha:**

```
echo '<div><table border="1">...Sénior</th><tr><td valign="top">';
                                                      ↑
```

**Nessas duas intersecções do meio:**

```
...
echo $tabela9;

echo "</td><td valign='top'>"; ←

echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#58ACFA"><h5><strong>Centro de Dia Utentes</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela5;
echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#FFFF00"><h5><strong>Centro de Dia Colaboradores</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela6;
echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center; background:#FF8000"><h5><strong>Total de Refeições</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela10;

echo "</td><td valign='top'>"; ←

...
```

Comment: pode parecer que me inspirei em alguma resposta, mas eu já estava trabalhando nela a partir do meu comentário na pergunta do AP e quando fui publicar minha resposta já tinha duas resposta. Não achei que devia jogar fora meu trabalho e publiquei assim mesmo!!!

Comment: De boas... tá valendo

Answer (score 2):

Também é possível alinhar direto pelo CSS

```css
.topo {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.base {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table height="100" border="1">
  <tr>
      <td class="topo">
        alinhado ao topo
      </td>
      <td class="base">
        alinhado a base
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```